# what's the difference between send ether and send offline on mew

Tags: myetherwallet

what are the differences between send ether/token and send offline using mew? 
I wasn't able to manually set gas price with send either/token, then I found out send offline lets me do that, I signed the transaction with my trezor and everything worked just like send either/token. I'm wondering why send offline is there, what's the primary use case for it?

[image]

Comment: The option for setting gas price in MEW for send ether/tokens is at the top of the site.